# Emacs lisp - extract number under point between two brackets

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm pretty new to Emacs Lisp and still learning how to do some of the basics.

I have some text like `[123]` and I want to extract the number `123`. I've goofed around with a few different attempts but I still can't seem to capture the number reliably. The closest I've gotten is extracting the character `]`.

Can anyone point me in a direction? My biggest struggle is in understanding how to capture the number once I've used `search-forwards` and `search-backwards` to capture the point positions of the brackets.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
(when (re-search-forward "\\[\\([0-9]+\\)\\]" nil t)
  (string-to-number (match-string 1)))
```

Alternatively, when the point is already on top of the number, `thing-at-point` may be more convenient:

```
(string-to-number (thing-at-point 'sexp))
```